# Size of a numeric class

Tags: matlab

The question *[How to know the size of a variable in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4845561/974555)* addresses how to tell the size of a variable in memory.  But is there any way of telling the size based on a numeric class?  What I'm looking for is a builtin function that implements a simple mapping table:

- `double` -> 8
- `single` -> 4
- `int32` -> 4
- `byte` -> 1

...etc.  Is there any function to calculate this, or do I need to implement a small table by myself?

Note that `whos` is *not* what I'm looking for.  Whereas `whos` shows memory usage for existing objects, I want to estimate the memory usage for data I don't have yet.

In `numpy`, I can achieve this using the `itemsize` attribute of the `dtype`:

```
In [6]: dt = dtype([("A", float32, (5,))])

In [7]: M = empty(5, dtype=dt)

In [8]: M.dtype.itemsize
Out[8]: 20
```

Comment: There's is no such function. Also, I think it's a waste of keystrokes, because if you're planning to estimate something, then it is up to you to specify a class, at which point you already know how many bytes, and I would rather type the number of bytes than a function name which is going to be longer. IMHO you have to be a little bit more specific on how you're actually trying to implement it for this question to be useful.

Comment: @OlegKomarov It's not a single class, it's 400 columns of data, some are `uint32`, some `single`, some `double`, etc.  I can loop through the columns and use a switch-case inside the loop to determine the size, but I wonder if there's a more straightforward way.

Comment: @gerrit: Wait...you said you didn't have the data yet; how do you know it will be 400 columns of data of variable class? How would you loop through the data if there is no data?

Comment: Will you have a cell array of strings saying which class?

Comment: I can still loop through the *columns* of my data-to-be without knowing how many *rows* I'm going to have, or even if I do know how many rows I'm going to have, but before I have calculated the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you need is a simple comparison of a cell array of strings (the class names) and map back the size in bytes of a single element of that class, then I would go with a hardcoded solution:

```
function out = class2byte(in)
numclass = {'double'; 'single'; 'int8'; 'int16'; 'int32'; 'int64'; 'uint8'; 'uint16'; 'uint32'; 'uint64'};
numbytes = [NaN;8;4;1;2;4;8;1;2;4;8];

[~,loc]  = ismember(in(:),numclass);
out      = zeros(size(in));
out(:)   = numbytes(loc+1);
end
```

An example:

```
>> class2byte({'single','singol','char','int64';'double','double','int32','uint8'}')
ans =
     4     8
   NaN     8
   NaN     4
     8     1
```

Comment: Yes, seriously; `eval`. Have fun trying to make a version of something that is as general as my 3-line solution (=10 lines when vectorized and able to accept cellstrings). Note that your solution 'neglected' `logical`, `char`, `struct`, `function_handle`, `cell`, all user-defined types and all Java classes. That'll take at least 50 lines to do properly, and quite possibly not even be faster. Sure, `eval` is a misspelling of `evil` for most places where it's used, but it really does have its proper uses; this is most certainly one of them. Performance isn't everything.

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis First of all, the question explicitly asked for numeric types and as such I ignored everything else on purpose. Second, your solution is apparently general. Now consider a couple of examples: 'cell(0)', 0 bytes, `cell(1)`, 8 bytes and `{[]}`, 112 bytes. Which one is sensible to pick? And with function_handles, `function_handle(0)`, errors (no constructor method). Therefore, I personally avoid `eval()` because most of the times inexperienced users will re-use it in a wrong way and will come back to ask incomprehensible questions decreasing the value of the content in the forum.

Comment: So a user-implemented uint256 wouldn't count as a numeric class in your book? And what about logical? which one is more sensible to pick: whatever the user gives you of course :) Moreover, the OP said he would give a *string*, not data. But whatever man, I gave a simple, general solution, you gave a complicated, more specific one. Downvote me if you feel the need. I'll upvote you because yours is good too :)

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis I was not aware there was such a thing as user-implemented numeric classes in Matlab... would that be a pretty advanced MEX-style file?

Answer (score 5):

Not sure why you don't want to use `whos`, because that's exactly how you would implement such a function:

```
function numBytes = sizeOf(dataClass)

    % create temporary variable of data type specified
    eval(['var = ' dataClass '(0);']); 

    % Use the functional form of whos, and get the number of bytes   
    W = whos('var');
    numBytes = W.bytes;

end
```

Use like so:

```
>> a = 4;
>> sizeOf(class(a))
ans = 
    8
```

Or, based on the way you're describing your data in the comments,

```
>>  your_data_cell = { 
        uint32(5)   int8(4)
        single(5)   char(4)
    };
>> cellfun(@(x) sizeOf(class(x)), your_data_cell)
ans =
     4     1
     4     2
```

I think `sizeOf()` is preferable over a direct mapping to internal data-types, because it would work just as well on user-defined data types which can be constructed by passing '0' to the constructor.

Comment: `eval()` seriously? Not to mention that a hardcoded version would be vectorizable and much faster.

Comment: Yes, `eval`, seriously. People tend to overuse it, making it wise to advise avoiding it at all cost, but that doesn't justify a blanket label of "evil everywhere always". It *has* its use-cases, as in this case: a direct mapping requires an ugly map, and cannot handle user-defined types.

Answer (score 0):

```
...
x = zeros(1,1,dataType);
numBytes = sizeof(x);
...

function b = sizeof(x)
   w = whos('x');
   b = w.bytes;
end
```

Comment: Please add some explanation!